# ASP.NET HTTPS/SSL Caching and Dynamic Pages

Tags: asp.net, caching, ssl, https, iis-6

I have an IIS6 ASP.NET 2/3.5 site that ALWAYS seems to be caching anything that goes through a https request. HTTP requests always work the same, but i see old/invalid data on https requests.

I see this a lot with pages where i'm doing http rewriting--but in general, it almost seems like the site has one set of values it shows to http requests and another to https requests-- without having any backend code that renders differently based upon the scheme.

Any ideas? Does IIS have a weird ssl caching option i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ports were set up wrong in IIS-- although the domain was correct because i was using port 443 it got forwarded to another site (because of host headers setup).